# How to read kml files in R without any error?

Tags: r, ggplot2, kml, r-sf, r-sp

I am trying to read the .kml which I downloaded from the link below:

https://data.opencity.in/dataset/delhi-metro-map/resource/delhi-metro-lines-map

However, I keep getting an error.

Here is a snippet of my code and the error:

```
library(geojsonio)
library(sp)
library(sf)

metro_lines <- st_read("MY_PATH/delhi-metro-lines.kml")
```

```
Reading layer `Delhi Metro Lines' from data source 
  `MY_PATH/delhi-metro-lines.kml' using driver `KML'
Error in CPL_get_z_range(obj, 2) : z error - expecting three columns;
```

Could you please help me figuring out what the issue is?

Thanks a lot!:)

Comment: When I run your code, there is no error?

Comment: This is strange. I am still getting an error. How are you passing the link to the file?

Comment: which version of {sf} are you using? There was a fix recently for the `z error` issue - https://github.com/r-spatial/sf/issues/1592

Comment: 1.0-9 - I downloaded it again just now. I tried updating it to 1.0.10, but even after following this link you shared, it is still 1.0.9.

Comment: Can confirm that updating sf to 1.0.10 from r-universe has fixed it and I can load linked kml. Windows 10, R 4.2.2 & `install.packages("sf", repos = "https://r-spatial.r-universe.dev")`

Comment: Every time I run this command, I get this error ```installation of package ‘/var/folders/n_/bkh_h2zx2617gksttxwl_5h40000gn/T//RtmpqghO6i/file1093e7ba7f309/sf_1.0-10.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status```. I have R 4.2.2 and MacOS 12.3